# Why do insertions and deletes take over 100 times longer on windows 7 than Mac 10.9?

Tags: python, windows, macos, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I wrote a script to benchmark insertions and deletes.

```
import os, time

abspath =  os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
dbname = 'test.sqlite'
# dbname = ':memory:'

databaseFileName = os.path.join(abspath, dbname)
if os.path.exists(databaseFileName):
    os.remove(databaseFileName)


from sqlalchemy import \
    Table, Column, MetaData, create_engine,\
    Integer, DateTime
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + dbname)

metadata = MetaData()
test = Table ('test', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

conn = engine.connect()

numRecords = 100

start = time.clock()
for i in range(numRecords):
    conn.execute(test.insert())
print 'It took %s seconds to insert %s records' % ((time.clock() - start), numRecords)

start = time.clock()
for i in range(1, numRecords+1):
    conn.execute(test.delete().where(test.c.id == i))
print 'It took %s seconds to delete %s records' % ((time.clock() - start), numRecords)
```

On Windows it printed

```
It took 5.32831616059 seconds to insert 100 records
It took 6.76065831351 seconds to delete 100 records
```

On Mac it printed

```
It took 0.036788 seconds to insert 100 records
It took 0.041629 seconds to delete 100 records
```

Why is it so much faster on Mac?  Is it because Mac uses HFS+ and Windows uses NTFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently SQLite performace on Mac vs Win has been a recurring issue.  See this discussion[from 2012](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Windows-slow-vs-iOS-OSX-fast-Performance-td65794.html).

One key feature seems to be sync parameters.

from the discussion:

> On Windows Sqlite by default uses the real/full fsyncs to the hardware
>   as  provided by the OS, while on at least OS/X, by default it doesn't.
>   See http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_fullfsync

Can you try running with pragma sync = off?

Comment: Thanks, here's the output for Windows `It took 0.086835328142 seconds to insert 100 records
It took 0.0872044052893 seconds to delete 100 records` when `PRAGMA synchronous = 0`