# What exactly are the symptoms of "database corruption" when OS crashes with PRAGMA synchronous=0?

Tags: windows, sqlite

I noticed the speed of inserts and deletes on Windows is about [100X faster in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161271/why-do-insertions-and-deletes-take-over-100-times-longer-on-windows-7-than-mac-1) when I set

```
PRAGMA synchronous = 0
```

However I'm concerned that

[*the database might become corrupted if the operating system crashes or the computer loses power before that data has been written to the disk surface.*](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous)

What exactly does "database corruption" mean?  Is the entire database inaccessible or is the data in a single field of a record malformed with all of the database accessible?

My only operations are inserts, deletes and update statements of a single row at a time.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the entire database inaccessible

This can happen.

> or is the data in a single field of a record malformed with all of the database accessible?

This can happen, too.

Another thing that can happen is that some data is missing.